# VisualForce, Listing Two Objects on a “single” Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have read most tutorials and googled a lot, with no success...

Let's assume that I have Two DB objects.

I'd like to have a "single page" that lists their records side-by-side. The result will looks like a grid UI.

Is it possible at all? I know that we can have an "extension controller" that takes care of some customized controller. I'm still wondering how I can retrieve records from TWO objects in a single controller ...

Any Suggestion, please ??

**P.S.** I've seen a solution [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1548/multiple-custom-objects-in-a-single-visualforce-page). What do you think ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to display two custom object record sets on the same page using custom grid UI.  The solution you've referenced is a start in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes @Soask . this is the right approach.  Only one custom controller can fulfill your requirement and the path is described in the link which you have pasted above.